# Access two-step-declared member in lambda setup

Tags: c++, lambda, nested

Don't know how to describe it better. Here's the code. This fails to compiler on gcc 4.9.2 (Debian 8.5), tough I think it compiled in a previous version. The problem seems to occur only if I access the later-declared structure's member as a default argument in the lambda setup. The other shown cases work.

```
// Test program
class C1
{
private:
    // Forward-declared
    struct S_Private;
    S_Private* d_;

public:
    void func();
};

struct C1::S_Private
{
    int a;
};

void C1::func()
{
    // This will work
    int test = d_->a;

    // Accessing the d_->a as a default argument in lambda setup
    // will NOT work:
    // error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘C1::d_’
    auto some_lambda = [&](int arg = d_->a)
    {
        // This will also work
        int test2 = d_->a;
    };
}

int main(void)
{
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately in `auto some_lambda = [&](int arg = d_->a)`, `d_->a` is not the `d_->a` you used earlier in the function but instead `d_->a` is being called on the `this` that you captured using `[&]`.  Because it is a member variable you cannot use it as a default argument in a function.

Essentially

```
auto some_lambda = [&](int arg = d_->a)
{
    // This will also work
    int test2 = d_->a;
};
```

Is

```
struct some_unique_name
{
    some_unique_name(C1*& var) : this_(var) {}
    auto operator()(int arg = this_->d_->a)
    {
        // This will also work
        int test2 = d_->a;
    }
    C1*& this_;
};

auto some_lambda = some_unique_name{this};
```

As you can see from the translation it uses the class member, not the object in the class itself.

Comment: `d_` is not captured. `this` is.

Comment: @aschepler Good call.  I think this captures better what is going on now.